# UnicodeEncodeError: trying to print win32_process (wmi module)

Tags: python, process, wmi, win32-process, kernel32

i'm trying to print all the process ( like task mannager), so i used 
this code :

```
from ctypes import *

import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()

kernel32 = windll.kernel32

i = 0

txt = ""

for process in c.Win32_Process():

    try:

        txt = txt + str(process)

    except:

        print process
```

most of the process (about 144/146) pass the try and then i print all together but there are about 2 process that fail the try, and the except and raise this error while i'm trying to print them:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 178-181: ordinal not in range(128)

someone know what to do?

Comment: try changing you `str(process)` to `unicode(process)` looking at the print statement you must be using python2, so strings are not unicode.

Comment: you are the best